# How to sign in and get user information from database at same time in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have small `firebase` project .

User can sign up with email and password and then store profile info photo uri, name, bio and location. So when user sign in first, I will check if the user is authenticated, then if task is successful I will request user info. Is there a way to do two task at same time?

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html   that was helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a code that I am using on my project.

```
  public void loginUserWithEmail(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d("mhstos", "signInWithEmail:success");
                user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    //Something went wrong
                } else {
                    userID = user.getUid();
                    if (userID != null) {
                        //addListenerForSingleValueEvent will be called once and then removed
                        mDatabase.child("users").child("email").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                //Retrieve the user details
                                FirebaseNormalUser firebaseNormalUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseNormalUser.class);
                                Log.d("mhstos", firebaseNormalUser.getFirstName() + " " + firebaseNormalUser.getLastName());

                                if (firebaseNormalUser != null) {
                                    MUser.getInstance().setFirstName(firebaseNormalUser.getFirstName());
                                    MUser.getInstance().setLastName(firebaseNormalUser.getLastName());
                                    MUser.getInstance().setEmail(firebaseNormalUser.getEmail());
                                    MUser.getInstance().setAuthToken(userID);


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }


                }

            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w("mhstos", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                try {
                    throw task.getException();
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "There is no user record corresponding to this email. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "The password is invalid. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("mhstos", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what happen if internet is disconnected at point of reading value from database ?.

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("mhstos", e.getMessage());
                }